# Having trouble finding a solution for Rails/Heroku: "The page you were looking for doesn't exist"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I signed up for the One Month Rails program a while back and am just now getting around to it. I've installed Rails, set up GitHub and Heroku. Everything seems to be working fine, the Rails test app runs on my local server, and I'm not getting any errors when pushing to Heroku but I keep getting "The page you were looking for doesn't exist."

I tried adding a root route, installing the 'pg' gem, running rake db:migrate, etc. At this point I've decided to delete the entire Ruby project, start over and re-install the 'pg' gem.

My Gemfile looks like this:
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.4'

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end



gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

gem 'spring',        group: :development
```

And my Heroku log looks like this:

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.6.3
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Using json 1.8.1
       Using minitest 5.3.5
       Using thread_safe 0.3.4
       Using builder 3.2.2
       Using i18n 0.6.9
       Using erubis 2.7.0
       Using rake 10.3.2
       Using rack 1.5.2
       Using mime-types 1.25.1
       Using polyglot 0.3.5
       Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
       Using coffee-script-source 1.7.0
       Using execjs 2.2.1
       Using thor 0.19.1
       Using hike 1.2.3
       Using pg 0.17.1
       Using multi_json 1.10.1
       Using bundler 1.6.3
       Using tilt 1.4.1
       Using sass 3.2.19
       Using rdoc 4.1.1
       Using tzinfo 1.2.1
       Using treetop 1.4.15
       Using rack-test 0.6.2
       Using coffee-script 2.2.0
       Using uglifier 2.5.1
       Using sdoc 0.4.0
       Using activesupport 4.1.4
       Using mail 2.5.4
       Using actionview 4.1.4
       Using activemodel 4.1.4
       Using jbuilder 2.1.1
       Using actionpack 4.1.4
       Using railties 4.1.4
       Using actionmailer 4.1.4
       Using activerecord 4.1.4
       Using sprockets 2.11.0
       Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
       Using jquery-rails 3.1.1
       Using sprockets-rails 2.1.3
       Using turbolinks 2.2.2
       Using rails 4.1.4
       Using sass-rails 4.0.3
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Bundle completed (0.61s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Asset precompilation completed (2.01s)
       Cleaning assets
       Running: rake assets:clean
-----> WARNINGS:
       Include 'rails_12factor' gem to enable all platform features
       See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-integration-gems for more information.

       You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
       To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
       ruby '2.0.0'
       # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for more information.

       No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, web, worker

-----> Compressing... done, 21.2MB
-----> Launching... done, v7
       http://immense-lake-7186.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Any help would be super appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Do the logs continue to show the server starting?  If not, try `heroku restart` and check the logs for error messages.

Comment: Also did you make _all_ the changes required in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4 including `database.yml`?

Answer (score 0):

**Error**

Firstly, having a Rails error of `The Page You Were Looking For Doesn't Exist` is a Rails error, not a Heroku one:

[image]

The difference is if you have a "Heroku" error, it's platform-level; meaning it will show when you have issues with your backend system (database, dependencies, OS, etc):

[image]

--

Since you're receiving the first (`red`) error, you'll want to look at what's happening to cause this.

If it happens when you first hit the application, it will probably mean you either don't have the `root` path declared *or* you don't have any `controller#actions` defined to handle the request.

I would try this:

```
#config/routes.rb
root to: "application#index"

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def index
    end
end

#app/views/application/index.html.erb
Test
```

When you push to `Heroku` again, you should try:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -a -m "Heroku"
$ git push heroku master
```